# in slickgrid how I can delete a row from a javascript function

Tags: row, slickgrid

how I can delete a row from a javascript function from a button
for example

Answer (score 16):

If you're using a DataView, use the following:

```
DataView.deleteItem(RowID);//RowID is the actual ID of the row and not the row number
Grid.invalidate();
Grid.render();
```

If you only know the row number, you can get theRowID using:

```
var item = DataView.getItem(RowNum);//RowNum is the number of the row
var RowID = item.id
```

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you are using jQuery

```
var grid;
$(function () {
   // init options, load data  
   ...

   var columns = [];
   columns[0] = { 
     id: 'id',
     name: '#', 
     field: 'id', // suppose you have an id column in your data model
     formatter: function (r, c, id, def, datactx) { 
        return '<a href="#" onclick="RemoveClick(' + id + ',' + r + ')">X</a>'; }
   }
   // init other columns
   ...

   grid = new Slick.Grid($('#gridDiv'), data, columns, options);
}
function RemoveClick(databaseId, gridRow) {
   // remove from serverside using databaseId
   ...
   // if removed from serverside, remove from grid using
   grid.removeRow(gridRow);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how i do it (not using any data provider though):

```
//assume that "grid" is your SlickGrid object and "row" is the row to be removed
var data = grid.getData(); 
data.splice(row, 1);
grid.setData(data);
grid.render();
```

I use this in a live project and it runs well. Of course, if you want to remove multiple rows then a few tweaks should be made, or if you use a data provider then you'd maybe want to remove the row only from the data provider and then have SlickGrid just refresh the rows.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function deleteRows() {
    var selectedIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows().sort().reverse();
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + grid.getSelectedRows().length + " row(s)?");
    if (result) {

      $.each(selectedIndexes, function (index, value) {
        var item = dataView.getItem(value); //RowNum is the number of the row
        if (item)
          dataView.deleteItem(item.id); //RowID is the actual ID of the row and not the row number
      });

      grid.invalidate();
      grid.render();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var rowsToDelete = grid.getSelectedRows().sort().reverse();
for (var i = 0; i < rowsToDelete.length; i++) {
    data.splice(rowsToDelete[i], 1);
}
grid.invalidate();
grid.setSelectedRows([]);
```

Answer (score -2):

yes of course, I use it this way

```
var selrow = grid.getSelectedRows (); 
data.splice(selrow, 1); 
grid.invalidateAllRows();
grid.render ();
```

Greetings

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SlickGrid> has no method 'removeAllRows' "

Answer (score -3):

hi
i'm used this script for delete row of SlickGrid

function deletefila(numrow)
{

```
  alert("delete row"+numrow);

  data.splice(numrow,1); 

    grid.removeAllRows(); 

    grid.render(); 

        //grid.removeRow(5);

        //grid.updateRowCount();

        //and then invalidate and re-render the grid by calling grid.removeAllRows() followed by grid.render().
```

}

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SlickGrid> has no method 'removeAllRows'